# JavaFx with Google Guice gives two different instances of Controller

Tags: javafx, fxml, guice, code-injection

I introduced Google Guice to my JavaFx applicatiomn. However I have some problem when I try to @Inject my controller into another controller.

First of all I do:

```
loader.setControllerFactory(Main.getInjector()::getInstance);
```

MainController has TopMenuButtonsController included in fxml file:

```
<fx:include fx:id="topMenuButtons" source="TopMenuButtons.fxml" />
```

Then I try to load my MainController using FXMLLoader with Guice Controller Factory. TopMenuButtons are initialized automatically because it's included to MainController.

Finally I try to inject MainController into TopMenuButtonsController (because buttons control what to display in MainController:

```
public class TopMenuButtonsController {

private MainController mainController;

@Inject
public void setMainController(MainController mainController) {
    this.mainController = mainController;
}
@FXML
public void onCreateOrder(ActionEvent event) {
    mainController.setCenter(MainController.CREATE_ORDER_FXML);
}
```

It succeeds but the instance injected here has all field set to null (@FXML annotation didn't work). I also see that this instance injected here is some different one than I use (different object id)

I can simply make it work by doing this in MainController:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    topMenuButtonsController.setMainController(this);
}
```

but my intention was to get rid of such things and use DI. What I can do?